# SharePoint 2010 Working with Multiple Document Libraries

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to figure out the best way to set up our extranet site which is used to communicate with the various organizations we contract with.  We partner with about 30 different organizations on a contract basis, and all the contracts, documentation, payment requests, etc. are uploaded by these organizations to our SharePoint extranet site.  Here's the basic rundown of the setup we currently have:

One Document Library per organization.  This means we have roughly 30 separate libraries.  We've discussed the option of just using one library for everything, but there does seem to be a benefit in having the work we do split this way.

We have one List we use as sort of a master contract tracking tool.  Each list item is one contract.  This is helpful in keeping things organized, but each individual contract can have a large list of requirements in itself.  I've been experimenting with InfoPath in creating custom form views that include project checklists within that single item, but haven't yet learned how that tool might help me tie it all together.

I need to learn how to fully capitalize on SharePoint 2010 in order to tie together the documents that 3rd party organizations upload into their separate document libraries into a project list that will track progress as efficiently as possible.

Any advice would be helpful!  Thanks!

Comment: I would create 30 subsites one for each organization. otherwise, you will have to grant permissions for each group (organization) individually.